# How to filter with graphene.filter

Tags: django, graphene-django

I want to filter Notifications by user.username, how can I do it?

models.py

```
class Notification(BaseModelo):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    state = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

schema.py

```
class NotificationNode(DjangoObjectType):

    class Meta:
        model = Notification
        filter_fields = ['user']
        interfaces = (Node, )

class Query(ObjectType):
    user = Node.Field(UserNode))
    all_users = DjangoConnectionField(UserNode)

    notification = Node.Field(NotificationNode)
    all_notifications = DjangoFilterConnectionField(NotificationNode)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the library `django-filter` and the standard Django double-underscore syntax for using attributes of a related model. Namely, you should write 'user__username' in your filter field.

```
class NotificationNode(DjangoObjectType):

    class Meta:
        model = Notification
        filter_fields = { 'user__username': ['exact'], }
        interfaces = (Node, )
```

You can see an example of this being used here: https://docs.graphene-python.org/projects/django/en/latest/tutorial-relay/#schema